# SUMIF Horizontal

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am searching for a column header and return a value under it.

Example:

_|A|B|C

1|X|Y|Z

2|1|2|3

If the value is 'Y', it must return '2'. I tried =SUMIF(A1:C1,"B", A2:C2), but realized that IFSUM does not support searching horizontal.

I would appreciate your support!

Comment: Have you looked into Hlookup?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb215308(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `SUMIF` not IFSUM - that works for any range, vertical or horizontal or even multiple rows/columns, as long as the value to return is numeric

`=SUMIF(A1:C1,"Y",A2:C2)`

AS Alan says, HLOOKUP would also give you the correct result and can return text as well as numbers

`=HLOOKUP("Y",A1:C2,2,0)`